# Send email with Python's smtplib - how to get appropriate login credentials?

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I have a domain-like email account at my University. I have a web interface (cpanel) to log in and check my mail. However, I would like to write a python script to send emails using my university account.

When I log in using cPanel:

```
Web address: infromatics.uniname.ny.us
Login: bbrown
```

I can successfully log in into my account. However, when I try:

```
Web address: infromatics.uniname.ny.us
Login: bbrown@infromatics.uniname.ny.us
```

I have the information that my login attempt failed.

So, there's a problem also with my SMTP request, at least I think I don't know how to handle it properly. Notice, that with the code below I don't have problems using my gmail account instead of university one, so I think the code is just fine.

I tried to check if I do it correctly with https://pingability.com/smtptest.jsp, here's its output:

**1. With credentials below:**

```
SMTP Server: unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us
From Email:smtptester@pingability.com  
SMTP Username: bbrown@infromatics.uniname.ny.us
SMTP Password: secretpassword
```

I have the output:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us", port 25, isSSL false
220-unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us ESMTP Exim 4.69 #1 Sun, 03 May 2015 11:49:25 +0200 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us", port: 25

EHLO localhost
250-unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us Hello pingability.com [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 78643200
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "78643200"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
YWlAaW5mb3JtYXRpY2EudW1jcy5sdWJsaW4ucGw=
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
YW5uYWxlc3VtY3MyMDE1
535 Incorrect authentication data

Authentication Failed
```

However, **2. With credentials below:**

```
SMTP Server: unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us
From Email:smtptester@pingability.com  
SMTP Username: bbrow
SMTP Password: secretpassword
```

Everything seems working fine:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us", port 25, isSSL false
220-unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us ESMTP Exim 4.69 #1 Sun, 03 May 2015 11:53:54 +0200 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us", port: 25

EHLO localhost
250-unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us Hello pingability.com [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 78643200
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "78643200"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
YWk=
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
YW5uYWxlc3VtY3MyMDE1
235 Authentication succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<smtptester@pingability.com>
250 OK
RCPT TO:<smtptester@pingability.com>
250 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   smtptester@pingability.com
DATA
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
Date: Sun, 3 May 2015 09:53:54 +0000 (UTC)
From: smtptester@pingability.com
To: smtptester@pingability.com
Message-ID: <9543385.63328.1430646834215.JavaMail.tomcat@localhost>
Subject: Pingability Test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Pingability Test
.
250 OK id=1Yoqay-0006kA-19
QUIT
221 unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us closing connection
```

However, with the below code:

```
import smtplib
import string

fromaddr = 'bbrown@infromatics.uniname.ny.us'
password = 'secretpassword'
toaddrs  = 'myfriend@gmail.com'
server_smtp = 'unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us'
port_smtp = 465


msg = 'Test message ^^'
BODY = string.join((
        "From: %s" % fromaddr,
        "To: %s" % toaddrs,
        "Subject: %s" % 'Hello!!!' ,
        "",
        'What\'s up? :)'
        ), "\r\n")

try :

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=server_smtp, port=port_smtp)
    server.set_debuglevel(True)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN PLAIN'
    server.login('bbrown', password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, str(BODY))
    server.quit()

except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected :
    print "smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected"
except smtplib.SMTPResponseException, e:
    print "smtplib.SMTPResponseException: " + str(e.smtp_code) + " " + str(e.smtp_error)
except smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused:
    print "smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused"
except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:
    print "smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused"
except smtplib.SMTPDataError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPDataError"
except smtplib.SMTPConnectError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPConnectError"
except smtplib.SMTPHeloError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPHeloError"
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError"
except Exception :
    print "Exception"
```

I have such output:

```
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us Hello [127.0.1.1] [x.x.x.x]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 78643200\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250 HELP\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us Hello [127.0.1.1] [x.x.x.x]
SIZE 78643200
PIPELINING
AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
HELP
Exception
```

How to deal with this?

================================================================

## **UPDATE:**

Thanks @Glueon for your help! Printing out the exception showed me:

```
Exception STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "umcstest_ai.py", line 32, in <module>
    server.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 637, in starttls
    raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

<class 'smtplib.SMTPException'>
```

So I edited my code to:

```
import smtplib
import string
import traceback
import sys

fromaddr = 'bbrown@infromatics.uniname.ny.us'
password = 'secretpassword'
toaddrs  = 'myfriend@gmail.com'
server_smtp = 'unismtpserv.uniname.ny.us'
port_smtp = 465

msg = 'Test message ^^'
BODY = string.join((
        "From: %s" % fromaddr,
        "To: %s" % toaddrs,
        "Subject: %s" % 'Hello!!!' ,
        "",
        'What\'s up? :)'
        ), "\r\n")

try :


    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=server_smtp, port=port_smtp)
    server.set_debuglevel(True)
    server.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN PLAIN'
    server.login('bbrown', password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, str(BODY))
    server.quit()

except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected :
    print "smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected"
except smtplib.SMTPResponseException, e:
    print "smtplib.SMTPResponseException: " + str(e.smtp_code) + " " + str(e.smtp_error)
except smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused:
    print "smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused"
except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:
    print "smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused"
except smtplib.SMTPDataError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPDataError"
except smtplib.SMTPConnectError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPConnectError"
except smtplib.SMTPHeloError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPHeloError"
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print "smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError"
except Exception, e :
    print "Exception", e
    print traceback.format_exc()
    print sys.exc_info()[0]
```

And the email has been sent! It's right here at my friend's mailbox, many, many thanks for help! :)

Just one more question: why the SMTP pinging page uses the 25 port with success and when I try to do the same, my attempts fail?

Comment: Isn't that a typo `server.login('bbrown', password)` ? Hardcoded login.

Comment: @Glueon: thanks, tried with `bbrown@infromatics.uniname.ny.us` but the output is the same, anything changed

Comment: Please print the actual exception instead of just 'exception'. Because I see it says 'Exception' at the end, but what exactly is wrong is not clear. Also as far as I understand `starttls` has to go before the `ehlo` call.

Comment: Your successful tests used port 25. Your code uses `port_smtp = 465`. What happens if you try `port_smtp = 25`?

Comment: Yes that might the problem because 465 is maybe SSL-only and does not support STARTTLS command.

Comment: @Glueon: thanks for your suggestions, they helped a lot. Now I'm just wondering why `https://pingability.com/smtptest.jsp` succeeded using port 25, and I had problems with it?

Comment: Lol at the base64 encoded auth info left in the post but in code it was redacted... and in one of the failed attempts the username has ".lublin.pl" tacked onto the end.  <scratching head but I ain't judging>.  3+ years later nobody has commented on this!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you tried to use the same code both with 465 and 25 ports.

Usually 25 port is used both for plain and encrypted mode. The second one is used when client issues the `starttls` command.

While 465 port is configured SSL only, that's why you get an error trying to execute `starttls` connecting to the 465 port. Server does not advertise this command.